# Does HighCharts have an option to dynamically add plotLines to xAxis via datetime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, highcharts

Hi I know I can add a plotline by defining a date time on the xAxis like so

```
xAxis: {
          plotLines: [{
          color: '#dadada',
          width: 1,
          value: Date.UTC(2016, 2, 28)
          }]
```

I want to dynamically add a plotline to each datetime day as new data is added from the database I'm using to the series.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ecgkcmf/

I want to achieve whats in the fiddle but dynamically without manually adding in all the values to account for past and future data

Does highcharts have a feature for detecting this or will I have to write some sort of complex loop and push the plotLines in?

Any guidance and solution is appreciated.

Comment: How are you adding new data? In that method you could check to see if you have crossed into a new day and then do xAxis.addPlotLine() (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotLine).

Comment: On the live server the new data will be pushed in at least daily from the database we are using so at minimum there will be a new datetime point on the x axis everyday

Comment: Okay, so then check to see what data is added that is within the date and add the plotLine via xAxis.addPlotLine(). If you know the last datetime added then you can calculate the xAxis value.

Comment: Can you show an example of this? This is something that should be automated. If a user wants to go back to 3/28/2010 they should see a line on that value the same way they should see a line on 6/11/2016

Comment: What does is the purpose of the plot line? Are you saying you want a plot line for each date?

Comment: Yes there should be a vertical plot line on each day just as is represented on the fiddle. The database will have years of data that the user can select a range of using a date picker. But it is a feature that the client requested.

Comment: If your tick interval is set to one day just set the `xAxis.gridLineWidth` to some non-zero value: http://jsfiddle.net/5ecgkcmf/1/

Comment: @wergeld that worked perfectly, can you put that in an answer so I can accept and upvote? Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you xAxis tick intervals are set to one day you can just make the xAxis.[gridlines](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.gridLineWidth) visible (they are set to `gridLineWidth: 0` by default:
$(function () {

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 2,
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        // one day
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }]
});
```

});